# open mp, c++, сортировка слиянием

Tags: c++, openmp

Проблема в правильной расстановке прагм(возможно использовании, есть предположение использовать task вместо section в pragma omp ...). Появляются данные, которых нет в исходных. И в закомменченом коде, подскажите правильна ли идея(если, размер сортируемых данных больше 3 элементов, то распараллеливаем, иначе всё выполняется в том же потоке).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
void merge(int *arr,int first, int last);
void mergeSort(int *arr,int first, int last);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int arr[1024*1024];
  int size=0;
  while(std::cin >> arr[size]){
    size++;
  }
  mergeSort(arr, 0, size);
  int i=0;
  while (i<size-1){
  std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
  i++;
  }
  std::cout<<arr[size-1];
  return 0;
}

void merge(int *arr,int first, int last){
  if (first==last) return;
  int *arr2 = new int[last-first+1];
  int start = first; 
  int middle = (last+first)/2;
  int finish = middle+1;
  for (int i=first; i<=last; ++i){
    if ((start<=middle) && ((finish>last) || arr[start]<arr[finish])){
      arr2[i-first]=arr[start];
      ++start;
    }
    else{
      arr2[i-first]=arr[finish];
      ++finish;
    }
  }
  for(int i=first;i<=last;++i){
    arr[i]=arr2[i-first];
  }
  delete[] arr2;
};
void mergeSort(int *arr,int first, int last){
  if (first<last){
//  if (last-first>3){
#pragma omp parallel sections shared(arr)
{
  #pragma omp section
  {
    mergeSort(arr,first, (first+last)/2);
  }
  #pragma omp section
  {
    mergeSort(arr,(first+last)/2+1, last);
  }
#pragma omp barrier
}
    merge(arr,first,last);
//  }
//  else{
//    mergeSort(arr,first, (first+last)/2);
//    mergeSort(arr,(first+last)/2+1, last);
//    merge(arr,first,last);    
//  }
  }
};
```

Comment: Вряд ли столь малое число, как 3 это правильный выбор. Поизмеряйте время работы, конечно, но imho правильная граница это *десятки тысяч* элементов.

Comment: @avp я с Вами ролностью согласен. Это тестовый код для набора не более 1024 на 1024. Данная реализация выполнялась в познавательных целях. на таком диапазоне я не получил прироста не с помощью tbb::parallel_sort, ни тем более с помощью собственной реализации через tbb. OpenMp при таком наборе также медленнее однопоточной реализации при приведенном коде, или же если заменить sections на отдельные task.

Comment: хотел повторить ваш код, но почему-то не работает #pragma omp barrier, ошибки что-то типо синтаксиса, но с ним все нормально

Answer (score 3, accepted):

прошу прощения за невнимательность, ошибка была в

```
main{
...
mergeSort(arr, 0, size);
...
}
```

должно быть так

```
mergeSort(arr, 0, size-1);
```